# Migrating from archlinux to gentoo

Tags: arch-linux, gentoo, migration

Is there an easy way to migrate from archlinux to gentoo? For example I get a list of manually installed packages in archlinux by `pacman -Qeq`, save it to file and edit (to delete all unneeded packages).

I'd like then to install that list of packages by `emerge`, but many packages have different names in gentoo and arch. Is there a way of automation of such package names conversion? Or I need to install package from list by hands, one by one?

Comment: You're better off doing it manually. That's just what Gentoo is like - you make your own rules, set your own USE flags, you know what is installed and why. Any kind of automation (even just an automated install) would give you a Gentoo system you probably wouldn't know how to maintain.

Comment: @frostschutz  That's bad: I have near 200 manually installed packages. Installation of some packages (with dependencies) is a very long process (for an hour or more), that's why I want to add some automation.

Comment: Get used to long compilation times, it comes with the territory :)

Comment: When I have to manually compile software on my workstation, I do so in my home directory, mostly for this reason.

Comment: @jordanm, I compile gentoo in chroot. I want first to install all packages needed for work, after that to setup everything (taking configuration files from arch) and only after that I will copy whole root directory to real partition (flash card) and try to reboot it. If everything would be OK, I will delete archlinux and copy gentoo instead of that dead system.

Comment: There is no automatic tool for the conversion. However when searching equivalent packages take a look at `app-portage/eix` to replace the painfully slow `emerge --search`. If you prefer, instead of listing all the packages you want to install on the command line you could also manually add them to `/var/lib/portage/world`, then `emerge world` after reviewing the `USE` flags.

Comment: @Eric, besides of main repository I use some overlays, however there are problems: I can't install freecad, kicad, tixguitar, xpdf and some other soft.

Comment: Maybe you can use pacman in Gentoo and installing your packages with pacman may be possible. It is important to notice that pacman will have nothing to do with portage. They are independent of each other. So, this may not be a good solution. And pacman in Gentoo portage is named as `sys-apps/pacman`.

Comment: @Eddy_Em: Please file bugs at https://bugs.gentoo.org when software doesn't build; yes, even for overlays (but make sure you state the overlay then as otherwise the bug might get closed or the maintainers confused).

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way.

pacman and portage are very different and have no connection to each other and as @frostschutz said manual step by step installation with understanding and customization on each step is the most sane reason to use Gentoo so it's just weird idea, at least in my understanding of things.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do some automation; and it is not by using the list of Arch Linux packages or installing an alternative solutin, but instead by using the list of installed files.

Meet [PFL](http://www.portagefilelist.de/site/start); the Portage File List, which keeps track of which files belong to which packages. So, theoretically, you could download the [MySQL dump of PFL database](http://files.portagefilelist.de/sqldump) (because you don't want to flood their server) and then query your entire partition against that database. As an end result, you should have a quite extensive list; it won't cover everything, but it should cover most.

What you do now is not throw this list into Portage; there is a good reason for that, which is that you don't want to explicitly merge dependencies. So, you will want to remove anything from your list which contains `libs/` or `/lib` to start with; that won't be enough, so you will want to do another manual run over it to ensure that it only contains the applications you actually use. Dependencies like libraries will be automatically pulled; so, they don't need to be explicitly merged. Explicitly merging them will be disadvantageous, because you are likely to pull incorrect versions.